# How to load a new version of emacs module from a file?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to debug a c++ program using `M-x gdb` but I get nothing but a `(gdb)` prompt.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662444/getting-gdb-to-work-with-emacs-24) has a comment which suggests to load the latest version of gdb-mi.el.

> Can you try download latest version of gdb-mi.el from github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el an try to load it?

Question: how can I load that version of [gdb-mi.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/gdb-mi.el)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading that file, you can load it with `M-x load-file`.

---

(Apart from that, `M-x gdb` usually just gives you a `(gdb)` prompt to start with. You have to start your program by entering `r`.)

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't gdb look somewhat like this: http://twimgs.com/ddj/images/article/2013/0613/debug6a.jpg

Comment: Not sure. I've never used it beyond typing things at the gdb prompt and stepping through code. Maybe those things are all built in, and I just haven't found them :)

Comment: Haha :) I will ask another question.